# cmake: how to pass a list of variables (from set) to code

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

I have been experimenting a bit with cmake recently and came across the `project` definition, where you can specify the name, version, description and languages.

I then learned that you can pass this information to the code, to print for example when the program starts, with the following lines:

```
add_compile_definitions( PROJECT_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}" )
add_compile_definitions( PROJECT_VERSION="${PROJECT_VERSION}" )
add_compile_definitions( PROJECT_DESCRIPTION="${PROJECT_DESCRIPTION}" )
```

I have been wondering how I can expand this to include the author's name(s) and/or license information. I started with the following:

```
set (
    PROJECT_AUTHORS
    fname1 lname1
    fname2 lname2
)
add_compile_definitions( PROJECT_AUTHORS="${PROJECT_AUTHORS}" )
```

This resulted in:

```
$ make src/main.i
Preprocessing C source to CMakeFiles/cmake_test.dir/src/main.c.i
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake_test.dir/build.make:87: CMakeFiles/cmake_test.dir/src/main.c.i] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:187: src/main.c.i] Error 2
```

If I then change the definition line to `add_compile_definitions( PROJECT_AUTHORS=${PROJECT_AUTHORS} )` (removed the `"`'s around the variable).
This results to just `fname1` in the code (as plain text, not a string)...

I then changed the `CMakeLists.txt` to:

```
set (
    PROJECT_AUTHORS
    "fname1 lname1"
    "fname2 lname2"
)
add_compile_definitions( PROJECT_AUTHORS="${PROJECT_AUTHORS}" )
```

Which resulted in:

```
$ make src/main.i
Preprocessing C source to CMakeFiles/cmake_test.dir/src/main.c.i
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake_test.dir/build.make:87: CMakeFiles/cmake_test.dir/src/main.c.i] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:187: src/main.c.i] Error 2
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how I could go about this?

For information:

- `cmake --version` -> `cmake version 3.19.2`
- `gcc --version` -> `gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`
- `bash --version` -> `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`

Comment: This is a question&answer forum. In the spirit of this forum, please ask a question, like you could change the title to "how do I pass a cmake variable list to C source file?" or similar. `in every case the compiler kept giving errors...` What errors? Please post the errors. Please post the verbose compilation command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple way would be to use a `configure_file`. Create a file:

```
# authors.h.in
#cmakedefine PROJECT_AUTHORS "@PROJECT_AUTHORS@"
```

Then:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
set(PROJECT_AUTHORS "fname1 lname1" "fname2 lname2")
configure_file(authors.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/authors.h)
add_executable(main main.c)
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen)
include(CTest)
add_test(NAME main COMMAND main)
```

and:

```
#include <authors.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char authors[] = PROJECT_AUTHORS;
    for (char *author = strtok(authors, ";"); author; author = strtok(0, ";")) {
        printf("%s\n", author);
    }
}
```

and after compilation:

```
$ build_dir/main
fname1 lname1
fname2 lname2
```

---

The problem is the `;` character that comes from concatenating the list variable in cmake into a string. Whereas `;` is the separator of arguments in CMake. You could replace `;` for example by `\;` and of course pass a value that is a C string literal. For example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
set(PROJECT_AUTHORS "fname1 lname1" "fname2 lname2")
# TODO: I think also escape "" or for example newline
# ie preprocess the value so that all is nicely parsed
string(REGEX REPLACE ";" "\\\\;" val "${PROJECT_AUTHORS}")
add_executable(main main.c)
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE "PROJECT_AUTHORS=\"${val}\"")
include(CTest)
add_test(NAME main COMMAND main)
```

with same `main.c` except `#include <authors.h>` and it also works fine:

```
$ cmake -S . -B _build -G Ninja && cmake --build _build --verbose && ( cd _build && ctest -V )
...
[1/2] /usr/bin/cc -DPROJECT_AUTHORS="\"fname1 lname1;fname2 lname2\""   -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o.d -o 
....
1: Test command: /tmp/10/_build/main
1: Test timeout computed to be: 1500
1: fname1 lname1
1: fname2 lname2
1/1 Test #1: main .............................   Passed    0.00 sec
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm!
Didn't know this existed, will definitely look further into it!

Is there a "best place" to store these "h.in" files? I currently have it my src dir

Edit: pressed enter to quickly...

Comment: `Is there a "best place" to store these "h.in" files?` Anywhere, there is no best place.

Comment: Alright, I think I will use a `gen` folder under my `src` folder then; to match the `gen` output-folder used by your suggestion.

Comment: `I will use a gen folder under my src folder then` I would advise not to. All build output files should be placed under BINARY_DIR. Otherwise, you will have problems differentiating output files from input files.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the compile definitions basically work like preprocessor `#define`s; you need to make sure the compiler will be able to use the valus in a menaningful way. Note using a list variable like

```
set (
    PROJECT_AUTHORS
    "fname1 lname1"
    "fname2 lname2"
)
```

in a string will result in the elements being semicolon separated; `PROJECT_AUTHORS="${PROJECT_AUTHORS}"` has the same effect as `PROJECT_AUTHORS="fname1 lname1;fname2 lname2"` and you probably won't be able to use `fname1 lname1;fname2 lname2` somewhere in your code.

If you want to use a string, you need to make the quotation marks part of the compile definition.

```
target_compile_definitions(myTarget PRIVATE "PROJECT_AUTHORS=\"${PROJECT_AUTHORS}\"")
```

Depending on your requirements you may want to generate code instead though and write it to a source file:

```
set(PROJECT_INFO
"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> GetProjectAuthors()
{
    return {"
)

foreach(_AUTHOR IN LISTS PROJECT_AUTHORS)
    set(PROJECT_INFO "${PROJECT_INFO}
        \"${_AUTHOR}\",")
endforeach()

set(PROJECT_INFO "${PROJECT_INFO}
    };
}
")

file(WRITE ${PROJECT_INFO_FILE} ${PROJECT_INFO})
```

Comment: Thanks that looks really interesting and useful!
`configure_file` was suggested in a different answer and I think that better suits my needs;
but I will keep this in mind for future references, because it looks very powerful!